# replace windows7 system files

Tags: windows-7, permissions

when,i often use cygwin & mingw,so much command like: find,convert,rm..etc.
but,i don't need windows7 inner commands. can't rename for windows7 commands, You need permission to perform this action. how to disable windows7 commands ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to have cygwin's commands to take precedence when there are duplicate commands in Windows platform? If so, you can simply rearrange your PATH environment variable, so the commands you want would take precedence. [This article](http://www.itechtalk.com/thread3595.html) talks about how to set/edit an environment variable in Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the commands that Windows uses are built right in to the command prompt and are a fundamental part of it, you will not be able to remove/delete them and even if you could, many items could fail as many third party programs launch scripts and the syntax between Windows and Cygwin programs will be different.